# docfx metadata step fails with error "Could not load SDK Resolver"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, roslyn, docfx

Whenever I try to build any documentation using docfx, I get the following error in the `metadata` build step that uses msbuild to analyze the xml comments in the code of the csprojs:

> Warning:MetadataCommand.ExtractMetadataWorkspace failed with: [Failure] Msbuild failed when processing the file 'C:\temp\docfxtest\docfx_project\src\src.csproj' with message: Could not load SDK Resolver. A manifest file exists, but the path to the SDK Resolver DLL file could not be found. Manifest file path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\SdkResolvers\Microsoft.Build.NuGetSdkResolver\Microsoft.Build.NuGetSdkResolver.xml'. SDK resolver path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\NuGet\Microsoft.Build.NuGetSdkResolver.dll  C:\temp\docfxtest\docfx_project\src\src.csproj

It seems that msbuild cannot be correctly resolved by docfx. Any idea how I could fix this?

Im using docfx version 2.56.5.0 on Windows and I also have VS Enterprise 2019 (16.8.2) and VS Build Tools 2017 (15.9.29) installed:

[image: Visual Studio Installer]

**UPDATE:**

I have now uninstalled the VS 2017 build tools completely and repaired the VS 2019 installation using the installer. I now get a different error when I run docfx. It seems that it can't find msbuild **at all** anymore.

> Warning:MetadataCommand.ExtractMetadataWorkspace failed with: [Failure] Msbuild failed when processing the file 'C:\temp\docfxtest\docfx_project\src\src.csproj' with message: The SDK 'Microsoft.NET.Sdk' specified could not be found.  C:\temp\docfxtest\docfx_project\src\src.csproj

Running `msbuild -t:restore,build` also shows that it can't find msbuild

> 'msbuild' is not recognized as an internal or external command

The targets are isntalled:

[image]

And so is the .NET Core workload:

[image]

Comment: Did you build the project successfully on VS2019 enterprise? And please let us know it is the issue of build tool itself or the project itself.

Comment: I can build the csprojs themself using VS. But I cannot build the docs for them using docfx. Docfx can’t find msbuild.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your **Build Tool for VS2017** might have some problems due to some issues. The most issue is this:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\NuGet\Microsoft.Build.NuGetSdkResolver.dll
```

Either you lost the dll or the dll is damaged.

**Update**

**1) First**, you should check whether you have installed `NuGet targets and build tasks` workload and `net core build tools` workload. If not, please install it.

[image]

[image]

**2) Second**, please delete `bin` and `obj` folder of your project and then try again.

You should use `msbuild -t:restore,build` to build your project.

**3) Third**, try to **Repair** from `vs_installer` for your build tool. It will repair the related dll. And then delete `bin` and `obj` folder, use build tool to test your project again.

**Important**:

**VS2017** does not support `net core 3.1`. You should note that. It supports <=`net core 2.1`.

So if you still want to use **Build Tool of VS2017** for your net core project, you should try the the above three steps and then target your project to `net core 2.1`.

**Besides**, if you start `msbuild` by **CMD**, I think you should check your environment variable **PATH** and check whether you have configured the `msbuild.exe` from **Build Tool of VS2017** on it. **Instead**, you could add `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe`. This way is for VS2019.

=================================================

**Update 1**

The problem is that you have already installed a `docfx tool` by [choco command line](https://dotnet.github.io/docfx/tutorial/docfx_getting_started.html#41-steps).

**At the beginning**, I always thought that you used [docfx.console](https://www.nuget.org/packages/docfx.console/) nuget package on your project and just invoke `docfx.exe` from `C:\Users\xxx\.nuget\packages\docfx.console\2.56.5\tools\docfx.exe` under command line.

**Regardless** of the installation of `docfx.console` package on your project, if you installed docfx tool by choco command and then just invoke `docfx.exe` on command line, it used the local `docfx.exe` under `C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\docfx\tools\docfx.exe` rather than the nuget package.

**So** the issue is that your local `docfx.exe` has some errors due to some issues. You should reinstall the `docfx.exe` by choco command `choco uninstall docfx; choco install docfx`.

Actually, directly use [docfx.console](https://www.nuget.org/packages/docfx.console/) nuget package on your project might be easier. From [this link](https://dotnet.github.io/docfx/tutorial/docfx_getting_started.html#3-use-docfx-integrated-with-visual-studio).

It already contains the generation step of the documentation by `docfx.exe`(from `C:\Users\xxx\.nuget\packages\docfx.console\2.56.5\tools\docfx.exe`) and will execute it automatically rather than run `docfx.exe` again manually.

Comment: I will try that. What is surprising to me is that it tries to use the build tools of VS 2017. I think it should chose and look for the build tools of VS 2019.

Comment: Also, if your project is target `net framework`, when you delete bin and obj folder, please run `nuget restore xxx/xxx.sln` first to restore the files.

Comment: All project are netcoreapp3.1

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, so you should use `msbuild -t:restore,build`.

Comment: Click `Lanuch` from the `vs_installer`,and it will use the related tool. If you start CMD to use msbuild on this way, you should check your environment variable `PATH` and check whether you have configured the msbuild.exe of `VS2017` on it. Instead, you could add `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe`

Comment: VS0217 does not support `net core 3.1`. It supports <=`net core 2.1`. So maybe you should make a choice. I have updated my answer. Also, developer command prompt for VS2019 is also what you want. You can search it from start menu. [https://i.stack.imgur.com/7oOBz.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7oOBz.png).

Comment: I have updated my question too. After uninstalling VS2017 and repairing VS2019 it can't find msbuild *at all* anymore.

Comment: How did you invoke msbuild, click Launch button under Build Tool of VS2017 from the vs_installer UI and then type msbuild? And if you use CMD, you should reconfigure the full msbuild.exe path into `PATH`.

Comment: I don't have VS2017 at all anymore now. I invoked msbuild using a new instance of a regular cmd.exe.  Using the *"x86_x64 Cross Tools Command Prompt for VS 2019"* I can sucessfully invoke the `msbuild -t:restore,build` command. But running docfx in that command prompt sill gives me the error *"The SDK 'Microsoft.NET.Sdk' specified could not be found."*.

Comment: Also, please check whether you have a system environment variable called `MSBuildSDKsPath ` and check the value of it is right on your current PC.  And make sure that the sdk version exists on your PC.

Comment: The thing that eventually fixed it was [reinstalling docfx](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65069800/4227) but who knows, the things from this answer might have helped too. So I am accepting this as the answer.

Comment: Oh, this is my guess. When you build your project in VS IDE(already install this nuget package docfx.console which contains the right `docfx.exe`), it has a custom script that uses the `docfx.exe` under the nuget package so that it works well. And your local `docfx.exe` is installed by choco command and the local `docfx.exe` might have some errors due to some issues. So, when you directly call `docfx.exe` on command line, it actually executes the local `docfx.exe` rather than the nuget package. Sorry for did not notice that you have also install a local tool on your PC at the beginning.

Comment: I always thought you used `C:\Users\xxx\.nuget\packages\docfx.console\2.56.5\tools\docfx.exe` directly on the command line. And that is called by VS IDE.  Anyway, thanks for your solution and have  a nice day ：））

Comment: If you did not install that `docfx.console` nuget package on your project, actually regardless of the use of this package on your project, when you directly use `docfx.exe` from the command line,checking the local docfx.exe might be a good choice. And I will update the answer to add them.

Comment: With latest `Visual Studio Installer version 3.4.2246.31370` there is not any `.NET Core Build Tools` checkbox available, you must install corresponding `.NET SDKs for Visual Studio` manually and then build tools will be added to Visual Studio automatically

Answer (score 1):

I have completely uninstalled docfx using chocolatey (`choco uninstall docfx`) removed every folder named `docfx`from `c:\ProgramData\chocolatey\.chocolatey\` and then reinstalled it (`choco install docfx`). After that, everything worked fine again. The file `c:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\docfx\tools\docfx.exe.config` contains a lot of msbuild related configuration. Maybe something was messed up there.